# Multiple Linear Regressions with Identical Slopes

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, linear

Is it possible to impose an identical slope during a multiple linear regression?

See below I have 3 sets of data with a linear fit y=ax+b. I would like to simultaneously impose the same a (while minimizing the error) and let excel return the b values for the 3 lines.

Thank you very much for any pointers.

[image]

Comment: Just to clarify, this is about three separate *simple* linear regressions, not about "multiple linear regression"; and you are trying to reuse the coefficient from set 1 (for instance) on set 2 and 3 and let excel find the best intercept?

Comment: Yes it is 3 simple linear regressions but that would be optimized simulatenously: I am hoping excel can not only find the intercept (b value) but also return the slope (a value) that minimizes the error on all 3 data set simulatenously. I do not want to impose manually the slope, I would like the find that "optimized" value.

Answer (score 2):

This is something where you push Excel to its limits, you might consider using more advanced statistical tools (e.g. R). But the following procedure might do the trick:

1. calculate the means of x- and y-values for all three data sets: $\bar{y}_i$, $\bar{x}_i$, $i=1,2,3$.
2. standardize your three data sets by subtracting the x-mean from the x-values and the y-mean from the y-values. If you use the standardize formula from Excel, provide $1$ as standard deviation. This step centers your scatterplots around the origin of the plot (effectively forcing the intercept in the regression to be zero).
3. now put the centered values from all three sets into one big set (concatenating all three sets of x-values and all three sets of y-values) into two new variables $x^{\ast}$ and $y^{\ast}$.
4. do the linear regression for this large set $(x^{\ast}, y^{\ast})$: you get an intercept of zero (or very close to zero) and one (!) slope $m$ that should be the best fit (or very close to it?).
5. the correct intercepts $c_i$ for the three original data sets are retrieved by solving $\bar{y}_i=\bar{x}_i\cdot m + c_i$ for $c_i$, where $\bar{y}_i$ and $\bar{x}_i$ are the calculated means for the data sets and $m$ is the fitted slope.

I'm not entirely sure if this all mathematically correct, but it should solve your problem with Excel's capability.

Comment: This is a nice work-around.  However, Excel has a built-in function `LINEST` to perform multiple regression, which allows it to make easy work of this problem.

Comment: How so? I guess one would need to specify additional variables which are constantly 1 in one group and 0 in another group to model the different intercepts. But I'm not familiar with ``LINEST`` (nor Excel).

Comment: Correct: you need to create dummy variables.  But that's a little bit easier than calculating the three pairs of means for the three datasets.  At the step where you write "do the linear regression," you are telling the OP to use `LINEST` anyway.  Thus, the natural workflow in Excel is the same as in any other statistical application: create the variables you need and apply the OLS fitting procedure.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how to use LINEST to solve the issue faced please? thank you very much

Comment: The usage of LINEST is `=LINEST(A2:A20;B2:B20)`, where your y-values are in cells A2 to A20 and your x-values are in cells B2 to B20.

Comment: Thanks Edgar. How can I impose the fact that the linear regression is performed on 3 sets on data simultaneously to obtain one single slope value? This is not clear to me, I am sorry.

Comment: I will try to provide an example data sheet soon.

Comment: @John, you can access an example data sheet [here](https://send.firefox.com/download/7a6f886d7cad5528/#kD2WoSVXd-TqO9doN94cAg). Please be advised that you cannot simply drag-and-drop your data into my sheet, since you need to adjust formulas to your ranges, especially the LINEST function. Excel is not the perfect tool for your task, consider it a work-around.

Comment: Thank you very much Edgar. I will study this example and adjust it where needed. A huge thanks again!